# Glue or other solution to repair broken plastic (polymer) part inside oven door

Tags: repair, adhesive, oven, plastic

On Christmas, when we were at a friends house, a piece of a plastic (or rather polymer based) part from the inside the oven door broke off (that is, a piece of a larger part broke off, not a single piece). With the piece missing, hot air can escape the oven at that location, thus it would be great to fix it.

We wondered if there is some kind of glue (or any other kind of method that does not require to replace the whole part) that you can use inside an oven to glue the broken off piece back in its place? It would need to be able to withstand oven temperatures (up to 250, better 300°C) and not emit any toxic fumes while doing so.

Comment: Just google "high temperature glue". The correct one may be dependant on what the broken part is actually made of. See https://www.masterbond.com/properties/high-temperature-resistant-bonding-sealing-and-coating-compounds for some examples

Comment: Would not hurt to see what the price is of that part.  Check from the maker, local stores and online.  Most parts are replaceable and google will find a how-to so you could do it.

Comment: Silicone will go very soggy at that temperature